# Center a div below the header

Tags: html, css

I added a widget area below my header and I try to center it just under the logo.

I tried to add `display: block` and `margin:0 auto` or `text-align: center` on `#header-sidebar`, but it doesn't work. Also, I tried to change the structure of the HTML code and not only make CSS tweaks, but still, the `#header-sidebar` stack on the left and not centered.

Here is my code:

HTML code:

```
<header id="header">

    <div class="header-container">

        <a href="javascript:;" class="show-on-phone show-on-tablet" id="phone-toggle-menu"></a>

        <a href="#" class="logo"><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="#"></a>

        <nav> //here is the navigation, hidden in mobile view </nav>

        <div id="header-sidebar" class="header-widget-area">
            <div class="textwidget">
                //some widget here
            </div>

            <div class="mlp_language_box">
                // some other widget here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>
```

CSS code:

```
header#header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: block;
}

header#header #phone-toggle-menu {
    left: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

header#header .header-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header#header .logo {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: do you want your logo to be absolute positioned?

Comment: @Chetan If I don't, it doesn't aligned center next to the toggle button for the mobile. At least, I couldn't find a way

Comment: @Tasos, Can you also share your css code for `#header-sidebar` or `.header-widget-area`

Comment: @RaviKhandelwal Actually, the proposed solution of Chetan worked as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:table` and `margin:auto` for both logo and widget area will do the trick... So toggle button alone can stay absolute.

```
header#header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: block;
}

header#header #phone-toggle-menu {
    left: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

header#header .header-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header#header .logo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

header #header-sidebar{
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to put the `nav` element which is between the two of them, but hidden in the mobile. However, it takes the place and the header-sidebar cannot stack below the logo. If I change the structure of the html and put the nav after the header-sidebar, will it work?

Comment: sorry, I dont understand, can you post the proposed markup and expected output.

Comment: I had a nav bar between the two, but moving it after, worked without an issue. I marked your answer as the right one. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css code with following :

```
header#header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: block;
}

header#header #phone-toggle-menu {
    left: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

header#header .header-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; 
}

header#header .logo {        
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
```